# OO design: If I am an object, should I create myself, or the thing that will use me

Tags: oop

Here's a question about software design. I'll give a concrete (but hypothetical) example that is easy to understand.

Imagine I am creating a daily deals website. I have two classes Deal and Merchant. In general should the createDeal() method be on the Deal class or the Merchant class?

The Deal class is a Deal so it makes sense to be there.

The Merchant is the one that creates the deal, so it makes sense to be there.

Or there may be a hybrid answer, or perhaps no specific answer.

Thanks in advance for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from *real-world perspective* it would make sense, if `Merchant` created each `Deal`.

But it falls apart when it comes to programming. Actually what you should have an instance of  `DealBuilder` (or factory .. there *is* a difference), which you provide to the `Merchant` in the constructor. Then the merchant can use this builder to create new `Deal` and add it to his list of current deals.

**Update:**

There is another way to organize this: you can create the instances of `Deal` outside the `Merchant`, and then `addDeal` to the merchant's "pool" of deals.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you decide to make the App work.

You can implement the Deal class to serve instances of itself (for instance a Singleton, but here is not the case), or you can have a method within the Merchant that calls for a new Deal.

In pseudo code, I think that your best approach should look similar to:

```
Class Merchant
  method offer_deal(var item, var discount)
    deal = new Deal();
    deal.item = item;
    deal.price = item.price * (1-discount);
    return deal;
  end_method

  ...

End_Class
```

I hope that helps you!!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a "has a" relationship between "Deal" and "Marchent". If I am not wrong then "Marchent" has "Deal".
"Deal" may be singular or plural.

My suggession you should Keep it in "Marchent".

But it totally depends on your requirement and architecture.